# How to get the name of the id and name of friend in the same output in sql

Tags: mysql

So I got 3 tables and I am struggling to get **name** of id and the corresponding friend id's **name** from Students table. Many thanks!

[image: f]

Comment: Join 2 copies of slave table - one joined to user, another to friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Database schema and data

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `Students` (
     `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `Name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

   INSERT INTO `Students` (`ID`, `Name`) VALUES
   (1, 'Ashley'),
   (2, 'Samantha'),
   (3, 'Julia'),
   (4, 'Scarlet');

   CREATE TABLE `Friends` (
     `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `Friend_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL ,
     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`, `Friend_ID`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

   INSERT INTO `Friends` (`ID`, `Friend_ID`) VALUES
   (1, 2),
   (2, 3),
   (3, 4),
   (4, 1);
   ```
2. Requested SQL qeury

   ```
   SELECT s.ID StudentID, s.Name AS StudentName, f.Name AS FriendName
   FROM Students AS s
   JOIN Friends AS s2f ON s2f.ID = s.ID
   JOIN Students AS f ON f.ID = s2f.Friend_ID
   ORDER BY s.ID;
   ```
3. Result:

   ```
   +-----------+-------------+------------+
   | StudentID | StudentName | FriendName |
   +-----------+-------------+------------+
   |         1 | Ashley      | Samantha   |
   |         2 | Samantha    | Julia      |
   |         3 | Julia       | Scarlet    |
   |         4 | Scarlet     | Ashley     |
   +-----------+-------------+------------+
   ```

Comment: you're amazing thanks!